# Route all HTTP traffic through polipo

Tags: iptables, proxy, cache, http-proxy, polipo

I've set up [polipo](http://www.pps.univ-paris-diderot.fr/~jch/software/polipo/) on my machine to listen to the default port `8123`. To test it, I set the in-memory cache to a ridiculously high 2 GB and downloaded a 50 MB file using `wget` utilizing the proxy.

```
http_proxy='http://localhost:8123' wget server/file
```

As expected, the first execution needs some seconds to transfer the file. Subsequent repetitions utilize caching and complete in less than a second.

Now, I want to try directing all HTTP (port 80) traffic to be automatically routed through `polipo`, so that I don't have to specify the proxy with each web browser, mail client or other program I use. Although [the faq indeed states that polipo is not intended for this use case](http://www.pps.univ-paris-diderot.fr/~jch/software/polipo/faq.html#featureshttp://), the Arch Linux Wiki mentions to do this via `iptables`

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m owner ! --uid-owner polipo -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8123
```

After executing these commands as root, I again issue the `wget` command without the proxy environment variable set. All invocations need to download the file again, caching is not utilized, which is also reflected by

```
$ iptables -t nat -vL
[...]
Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 5 packets, 529 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    6   312 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http ! owner UID match polipo
    0     0 REDIRECT   tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http redir ports 8123
[...]
```

Only the `ACCEPT` rule is triggered, not the `REDIRECT` directive. I also tried to reverse the filter. Note the missing negation `!`.

```
iptables -t nat -R OUTPUT 1 -p tcp --dport 80 -m owner --uid-owner polipo -j ACCEPT
```

Thereafter, only the second rule was utilized, redirecting all HTTP traffic to always return the `polipo` configuration interface.

How do I configure `iptables` correctly to route HTTP traffic through `polipo`? Is it even possible? Or do I have to switch to the more heavyweight [squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/)?